# Селектор по атрибуту jQuery не выбирает элемент

Tags: jquery

```js
var div = $("div[product_id='1']");
console.log(div.attr("product_id"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div product_id="1" class="col s12 m6 l4 forFilter">
  <li class="collection-item avatar info" showinfoid="1">
    <img src="images/goods/42x42/product_1.jpg" alt="Помидоры" class="circle">
    <span class="title truncate">Помидоры</span>
    <p class="truncate">Москва<br>
      <span class="price-measure"><span class="price">50₽</span>/кг</span>
    </p>
    <div class="input-group">
      <button class="minus">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
     </button>
      <span class="good" id="1" name="Помидоры" category="Овощи и зелень" manufacturer="Махачкала" measure="кг" price="50" tocart="1">2</span>
      <button class="plus">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
     </button>
    </div>
    <p></p>
  </li>
</div>
```

Возвращает undefined. Это как-то связано с тем, что внутри `<div>` у нас `<li>`?

Comment: Если вы нажмёте кнопку "Выполнить код", то заметите, что он работает и undefined не возвращает.

Comment: И нельзя в теги писать любые атрибуты, какие придут в голову. Атрибут `product_id` делает ваш html-документ невалидным.